# Use Count() with self join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, count, self

I'm working with the northwind database and my exercise is:

> Which suppliers offer two products in the same category? Show company name, category and the both product names

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.CategoryID, s.CompanyName, p1.ProductName, p2.ProductName
FROM 
    Suppliers s 
INNER JOIN 
    Products p1 ON s.SupplierID = p1.SupplierID
INNER JOIN 
    Products p2 ON p1.CategoryID = p2.CategoryID 
                AND p1.ProductID <> p2.ProductID
INNER JOIN 
    Categories c ON p2.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
GROUP BY 
    c.CategoryID,s.CompanyName, p1.ProductName, p2.ProductName`
```

How can I filter that with `COUNT()` I tried to do it with `HAVING` but I failed.
I'll appreciate some help, which bringing me back on the right way.

Comment: Kindly provide sample data and your expected result

Comment: What is your desired output format?  Your current query will not return a sensible result for suppliers with 3 products.  Do the products have to be in seperate columns or can you just have two rows per supplier?

Comment: It should be a row with the supplier name, both products which have the same category id and the category id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Gordon's answer the code below will get all the data you need.  If you absolutely have to have both products in the same row, you can use `pivot`:

```
select s.CompanyName
        ,p.ProductName
from Suppliers s
    -- This join filters your Suppliers table to only those with two Products in the same Category
    inner join (select SupplierID
                        ,CategoryID
                from Products
                group by SupplierID
                        ,CategoryID
                having count(1) = 2
                ) pc
        on(s.SupplierID = pc.SupplierID)

    -- This join returns the two products in the Category returned in the join above.
    inner join Products p
        on(s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
            and pc.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
            )
```

Comment: i tried to do it with 
PIVOT
(
p.ProductName
FOR SupplierID IN ([250], [251]) AS pvt
)

i pretty much copy pasted it from the https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx but it seems to have an syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of suppliers/categories with exactly two products using a query like this:

```
select supplierId, categoryId
from products
group by supplierId, categoryId
having count(*) = 2;
```

Then, write a query to show the supplier and products names, and use the above to filter the results from that query.  You can use either `exists` or an additional `join`.